# Hibernate Upgrade : Unknown service requested

Tags: java, hibernate, upgrade

Previously I was using `hibernate 3` as my project framework and I upgraded it to the `hibernate 4.3.5`.

I followed these steps:

1. Replaced all the `.jar` files & also the dependent `.jars`
2. Replaced all deprecated packages
3. Replaced all the deprecated methods
4. Replaced all the deprecated Data types, classes & others.

After this build my project successfully & then try to connect with the database. Connection is successful but when i am trying to save, It gives me following error:

```
Unknown service requested 
[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.JdbcServices]
```

Is there something that I missed out ? Please Help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the Solution for My problem:

Session object in Hibernate is not thread safe, you should not use the same session in different threads, unless you synchornize access to Session object.

Reference : [Hibernate Upgrade : Unknown service requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266750/hibernate-unknownserviceexception-unknown-service-requested-as-transaction-comp)